# TypeError: Class constructor model cannot be invoked without 'new'. I am not using typescript

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am new to sequelize orm.

While developing backend with express, sequelize and mssql, I created models with sequelize-cli.

Before I have index.js file and new models created by seqeulize-cli command 'sequelize init' and 'sequelize model:generate..", I had no issue.

But as I start the server I encountered the error saying "TypeError: Class constructor model cannot be invoked without 'new'".

I have not touched index.js file and the new model generated by sequelize-cli is class-basis.

I tried to change class-basis model to sequelize.define() but still get the same error.

Please help me resolve the issue.

Thanks!!

Here is my code.

index.js

```
"use strict";

const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const process = require("process");
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const config = require(__dirname + "/../config/config.json")[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.username,
    config.password,
    config
  );
} else {
}

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file) => {
    return (
      file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === ".js"
    );
  })
  .forEach((file) => {
    console.log("##########", path.join(__dirname, file))
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(
      sequelize,
      Sequelize.DataTypes
    );
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

GroupCode.js

```
"use strict";
const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class GroupCode extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate({ CommonCode }) {
      // define association here
      this.hasMany(CommonCode);
    }
  }
  GroupCode.init(
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
      },
      description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
      active: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: true,
      },
      createdBy: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
      updatedBy: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "GroupCode",
    }
  );
  return GroupCode;
};
```

CommonCode.js

```
"use strict";
const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class CommonCode extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate({ GroupCode }) {
      // define association here
      this.belongsTo(GroupCode, {
        foreignKey: { name: "groupCodeId", allowNull: false },
      });
    }
  }
  CommonCode.init(
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
      },
      value: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
      },
      seq: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        default: 1,
      },
      active: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: true,
      },
      createdBy: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
      updatedBy: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "CommonCode",
    }
  );
  return CommonCode;
};
```

Resolve the error that appears when start the server.

Comment: What is the full error message, including the whole stack trace?  And, thus exactly what line of code does the error originate on?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).